# Is there a way to stack multiple route resolvers into one?

Tags: angular, typescript

So I'm tasked with redoing a lot of the work for the resolvers in my project, and I was wondering if it's possible to stack multiple resolvers into one.

For example, let's say my pages are separated into

- ### Product list (url /product) -> has a resolver for a findPageable at page 0
- update (url /product/:id) -> has a resolver for a findById or something like it and another resolver for a configuration list
- create (url /product/new) -> only has a resolver for said configuration list

I know it should be possible to use different resolvers, but I was wondering about using a RxJS operator to combine two Observables into one or something like this? Is it possible?

Comment: Yes you can use operators like `merge, concat, forkJoin etc.` Make multiple requests and await them.

Comment: @Eldar Is it a good idea though? Like, is it the best practice doing this in said scenario? Or is it better to simply do them separately?

Comment: I would prefer a more granular approach. Keep the resolvers separate and configure your routes to use multiple resolvers as they may require. You can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42564216/12354911) for a sample of it.

Comment: @Eldar thanks a lot! If you don't mind, write a normal answer so that I can give you the solution answer

Comment: It's ok for me. Glad if it helped.